# OpenLDAP chain overlay configuration

Tags: redhat, openldap

I'm trying to get OpenLDAP's chain overlay to work, but unfortunately, the documentation is rather sparse.

I'm using the OpenLDAP version 2.4.39 packages that come with RHEL 6, and the LDAP master and slave are using TLS to communicate. The TLS certs and keys are stored with Mozilla NSS, so the `tls_certdir` and `tls_cert` statements below should be correct (they definitely work in this form for replication).

My configuration (in `slapd.conf` form, which I convert to OLC notation before using) is:

```
overlay chain
chain-uri              ldap://my.ldap.master.example.com
chain-rebind-as-user   FALSE
chain-idassert-bind    bindmethod="simple"
                       binddn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
                       credentials="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                       mode="self"
                       starttls=yes
                       tls_reqcert=demand
                       tls_cacertdir=/etc/openldap/certs
                       tls_cert=my.ldap.slave.example.com
chain-tls              start tls_reqcert=demand tls_cacertdir=/etc/openldap/certs tls_cert=my.ldap.slave.example.com
chain-return-error     TRUE

[...syncrepl...]

updateref       ldap://my.ldap.master.example.com
```

I want to get this working so that policy updates get forwarded onto the master (eg, when someone gets their password wrong five times or more, the slave will send the pwdAccountLockedTime to the master, rather than storing it locally). I have ppolicy_forward_updates set in the config file, for this purpose.

I have tested this and am not seeing any traffic going to the LDAP master when I make changes on the slave.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This won't solve the problem you're currently facing, but maybe it's helpful nonetheless: OpenLDAP supports master / master replication. If using this, you wouldn't need the chain overlay.

Comment: Yep, I have multi-master replication going, but also a bunch of slaves that talk to those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure the `chain` overlay is configured on the `frontend` database and not the `hdb`/`mdb`/`bdb` database. So in your `cn=config` database you should end up with the following entries:

- `olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config`
- `olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config`
- `olcDatabase={0}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config`

I had the same problem where I had configured the overlay on the main `hdb` database and had the same symptoms where there was no traffic from the slave to the master. As soon as I re-parented the overlay and its database to the `frontend` database it started to work.

You may also need to configure the `olcAuthzPolicy` attribute on the master server.